# MySQL, moving first word to last

Tags: mysql

How would I move the first word, if it was the word 'the', to the end of the cell in MySQL?

As an example:

before: The Good, the Bad and the Ugly
after: Good, the Bad and the Ugly, The

Thanks

Comment: Hi FEB, can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with thecoshman that you should be careful not to do too much processing on the SQL side, but the following query may accomplish what you're looking for:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
        SUBSTR(col, LOCATE(' ', col)+1), 
        ' ', 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', 1)
    ) FROM table;
```

Comment: thank you very much - I will try this later tonight. I appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't use SQL for this. SQL is for querying databaes. You would read that value from the database, edit it with some code such as PHP, perl, ruby, C#, ASP etc. etc. Then write the value back into the database.

Comment: You're right - if I cannot accomplish this 'easily' I will go down the php route. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to change the data in the existing table?

```
UPDATE films
SET title= CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTR(title, 5, 1)), SUBSTR(title, 6), ', The')
WHERE title LIKE 'The %';
```

However I agree with thecoshman: this is usually better done in a code outside the database. SQL's string-processing abilities are generally weak and inconvenient compared to a real scripting language.

Comment: this looks like it may be the way - I'll try later tonight. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Small correction in your query, but nice result.

```
SELECT CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING(col, LOCATE(' ', col)+1), 
        ' ', 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', 1)
    ) FROM table;
```

Comment: `SUBSTR()` is a valid alias for `SUBSTRING()`, at least in the versions of MySQL I'm familiar with. Older versions may be senile and rude, so your mileage may vary. :)

Comment: yes i accept only version support problem is there, so only i used that